# Why Simplify[1/Sqrt[a] == Sqrt[1/a] doesn't give a "true" output in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equals, sqrt, simplification

In Mathematica, `Simplify[1/Sqrt[a] == Sqrt[1/a]]` gives `Sqrt[1/a] == 1/Sqrt[a]`. I don't really see why this doesn't give a `true` output when, `FullSimplify` gives the desired result.

This probably is a very dumb question, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if a<0 then sqrt can have complex output values.

For example

```
sqrt(1/-1)=i
```

while

```
1/sqrt(-1)=-i
```

See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify assumptions to `Simplify`.

```
Simplify[1/Sqrt[a] == Sqrt[1/a], a >= 0]
(* True *)
```